# strange! functions were kept calling after animation is finished?

Tags: ios, animation

I am currently encountered a weird problem doing animation:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{lblBonus.alpha=0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [lblBonus removeFromSuperview];
                        NSLog(@"finished");
                        [self updateNewRecord];
                        [self clearScreen];
                        [self btnStartPlaying];
                         [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
                     }];
```

all the functions were kept calling until the app is crashed, but the "NSLog" shows only one time if all the functions were removed:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{lblBonus.alpha=0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        NSLog(@"finished");
                     }];
```

anything is wrong?? anyone ever encountered this same problem???

Comment: Presumably one of the methods in your completion block calls the animation again?

Comment: Most likely the methods call the animation code themselves. Place a breakpoint at that to figure out how.

Comment: may be one method of`[self updateNewRecord];[self clearScreen];[self btnStartPlaying];` invocate the animation

Answer (score 0):

yes, finally I found that the animation was calling repeatedly by a timer..I must be too tired sitting whole day in front of the MACbook,,,